# Pithy English phrase that precisely means "only and all" the items in a category

Tags: phrase-requests

How can we ask someone to display "all the items that are fruits and only items that are fruits?"

If we ask someone to display "all the items that are fruits", then the display could reasonably display *all the fruits* and also some other random items like goats.

If we ask someone to display "only items that are fruits", then the display could reasonably display *some of the items that are fruits* and exclude many of them like oranges.

Does a simple phrase exist to express this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to express this is simply the reverse of your *only and all*:

> Display **all and only** items that are fruits.

> What about "**all and only** horses gallop?" This states that all
> horses gallop and only horses gallop... [Nicholas Smith; *Logic: The
> Laws of Truth*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Logic/wlL2GHt1gS8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=what%20does%20all%20and%20only%20mean&pg=PA181&printsec=frontcover) (2012)

> Consider, for example, some word that means DOG. Its meaning determines its extension—i.e.
>
> x means DOG → x expresses a concept that is true of **all and only**
> dogs
>
> or, in other words,
>
> x means DOG → x is true of **all and only** dogs,   where, by
> definition, a predicate is true (italicized) of a thing if and only if
> the concept it expresses is true of that thing. [Paul Horwich;
> *Meaning*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Meaning/BBQP72IXqsMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22all%20and%20only%22%20meaning&pg=PA28&printsec=frontcover) (1998)

> We do want to say, however, that **all and only**
> bachelor-descriptions are unmarried-man—descriptions, and that all
> rabbit-descriptions are animal-descriptions. [Edward Becker; *The
> Themes of Quine's Philosophy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Themes_of_Quine_s_Philosophy/_vkfAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22all%20and%20only%22&pg=PA263&printsec=frontcover) (2012)

> Human beings are fundamentally similar, from this point of view, when
> they are capable of acquiring and of manifesting **all and only** the
> same semiotic tendencies under the same causal conditions. [J. Fetzer;
> *Computers and Cognition*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Computers_and_Cognition/sM-JnRmcH4EC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22all%20and%20only%22&pg=PA95&printsec=frontcover) (2001)

> Property designators with more than one potential designatum of the
> relevant sort include general descriptions that fail to inform us much
> about the designatum, like 'the *property* that is instantiated by
> **all and only** items that are the color of Antarctica' or 'the *entity* that is instantiated by **all
> and only** quantities of the brand of soda endorsed by Ray Charles'.
> [Joseph LaPorte; *Rigid Designation and Theoretical Identities*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rigid_Designation_and_Theoretical_Identi/wwrvRE5ci20C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22all%20and%20only%20items%20that%22&pg=PA31&printsec=frontcover)
> (2013)

> ... where Aristotle distinguishes 'definition' from 'unique property'.
> These two have the same extension–they pick out **all and only** items
> that fall under a term–but [']definition['] picks out the essence, while
> 'unique property' does not. [J. Bryan et al; *Authors and Authorities
> in Ancient Philosophy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Authors_and_Authorities_in_Ancient_Philo/EnpnDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22all%20and%20only%20items%20that%22&pg=PA136&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

---

In logic *if and only if* has the shorter form

> **iff** (conjunction)
>
> If and only if
>
> *Two figures are congruent iff one can be placed over
> the other so that they coincide.*
>
> —used in logic and mathematics
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iff)

However, I've never seen anything shorter than *all and only*.

Informally, we might say "List **just** the verbs in this passage," where one could reasonably assume that "just" means *all* the verbs in addition to *only* the verbs.

Comment: @jsw29 You are right--corrected. Thank you.

Comment: **Iff** one is in a setting in which *iff* is a readily understood expression, one can always use it instead of *all and only*: for example, 'display all and only fruit' is logically equivalent to 'if and only if something is fruit, display it'.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a given set of items and you want to request a subset that is only fruit (there are no non-fruit items, maybe not all the fruit items but no no-fruit ones) in the subset, -and- the subset that is all of the possible fruits items (there might be some non-fruit items, but the point is to have every one of the fruit items of the bigger set in this smaller set), then the most succinct way to refer to this subset is:

> display **exactly** the items that are fruits.

'all' could be more items, 'only' could be fewer items, but exactly gets you the subset that is the overlap of these two, both all and only.

While this might be considered an inference from the [overt definition of 'exactly'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exactly), the same could be said for ['all'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all) and ['only'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/only). This usage is prevalent in more formal or technical situations.